# How to integrate a paypal button to a shopping cart website that has multiple payment method

Tags: php, paypal

Please help am new in web development and am trying to build a shopping cart website that has multiple payment method But i don't know how to integrate paypal to the website because am using radio button to choose between different payment method, please someone should help please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfuey.png)

Comment: You can generate custom Pay now button on [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/) website.

Comment: What i don't understand is that do i need to remove the paynow button that has been add before in my code?

Comment: Well, PayPal generates a form with a button to send, you can reuse your button and send the PayPal form.

Answer (score 0):

Is this screenshot something you developed, or some out-of-the-box / third party software you installed?

- It looks just like many third party shopping carts that have a
  pre-integrated PayPal payment method already activated. In that case,
  you need to ensure it is configured correctly to point to the PayPal
  Business account that is going to receive payments (using either its
  email address or API credentials, whatever its settings call for)
- If it is something you developed and we are just looking at a mock
  UI, then you should integrate a PayPal Checkout, documented here:
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

  Some skeleton code demos can be found here:

  - Client-side only solution: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client
  - UI for solution that also implements server-side v2/orders API calls: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

    (If you do a server-side solution, don't neglect to [handle funding source errors](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/) after you get the happy path working)

Comment: Yes sir it is something developed from scratch, i will try to integrate the paypal button now, thanks.But what i don't understand is that if i integrate the paypal account do i still need to add code a page to collect the customer shipping address if after he/she has finished paying through paypal or is it paypal that will have to do that?

Comment: Thank you sir once again the smart pay button is the best for the website thanks a lot i was using the pay now button before i that one got me more confused